# Alternative to Conversational Actions for audio streaming

Tags: actions-on-google

As many others are, we are severely impacted by the sunsetting of Conversational Actions and have no viable solution to our live streaming (audio) action. We're looking for a solution for our radio station using the "Hey Google, play (station name)" and plays a live audio (MP3/AAC) audio stream.

Does anyone know/have a solution for this before the sunset deadline of 2023?

What are other people doing about this?

One of the only things I can see is "Media Actions" but this seems to be closed to a limited number of people at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/advice.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have a solution or update to the successor of this feature. We will update our public documentation as soon as we have any update in this regard. In the meantime, you can open up a ticket on the [public issue tracker](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/) in this regard.

Comment: Hi there, when you say "we", do you work at Google on the Actions team? If yes, I am trying to reach someone regarding Media Actions. We have many customers impacted by this, is there anyone we can speak to? Have raised multiple support tickets but not been able to discuss this with anyone.